# NHibernate exception: Transaction not connected, or was disconnected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

In our develop environment all the ASP.NET application works just fine. However, when I deploy the site on the test machine, on some pages I get this exception:

```
NHibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not connected, or was disconnected
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.CheckNotZombied() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Transaction\AdoTransaction.cs:line 406
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Rollback() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Transaction\AdoTransaction.cs:line 240
```

I have no idea on how to solve this issue. The only difference are the DB versions:
Develop: 10.0.5500 (2008 R2, SP1, Express)
Test: 10.0.5500 (2008, SP3)

Does someone has an idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a problem with your session-per-request pattern implementation. ASP.NET is multi-threaded and the session is being closed when a thread terminates instead of when the request ends. There are many [examples](http://lozanotek.com/blog/archive/2009/02/17/Contextual_Sessions_with_NHibernate_ndash_Part_1.aspx) of how to manage session-per-request and NHibernate has a built in [NHibernate.Context.WebSessionContext](http://nhforge.org/wikis/reference2-0en/context-sessions.aspx) but I prefer to use a dependency injection framework such as [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I (finally) figured it out. There was a trigger which causes an exception, which in turn caused a rollback.

Answer (score 31):

This was a comment, but I had the same issue as well.

This error can occur when a trigger causes a database level exception. This will cause the transaction to be rolled back hence the exception.

Comment: True, in my case, I was inserting a string that was longer than what the database field accepted. The error message is not very useful.

Comment: Yep.  I had some data type mismatch in the inserted data, and I got this incomprehensible error from NHibernate.  Would have been nice if they could have just passed through the error from Sql instead of this confusing nonsense.

Comment: you can use the SQL Profiler to get the underlying script/command that caused the error. am a bit surprised the error doesnt bubble up correctly

Comment: In my case it was caused by a very slow sql query (took 34s to execute), so I added an index to make the sql query fast, and that fixed the issue. Not sure why the proper exception didn't bubble up (e.g. "timeout", etc).

Answer (score 0):

Another problem could be the user security (a database level exception again).
In my case the underlying DB problem was:

```
The server principal "AppUser" is not able to access the database "AppDB" under the current security context.
```